# How to programmitically create a folder?

Tags: android

```
String myfolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + folder_main;
File f = new File(myfolder);
if (!f.exists()) {
     if (!f.mkdir()) {
         Toast.makeText(this, myfolder + " can't be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
         Toast.makeText(this, myfolder + " can be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

Comment: **Welcome to stackoverflow** Please Read **[Necessary things to read while asking  a good question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 0):

For create new folder

```
File targetFolder = new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +"Folder Name");

if (!targetFolder.exists()) {
        targetFolder.mkdir();
}
```